# Facebook LIKE button on site

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like

I just want to know, my LIKE button on my site www.topofthetables.com is it conected to my 
facebook page? What can I do to connect the amount of likes to my facebook page? Thank you!

Comment: Change the `href` to your Facebook page. But this way, people will no longer *LIKE* your website with that like button!

Answer (score 0):

The `Like`s on your website are connected to your website and not connected to the Facebook page.  You can't get the 2 connected together unfortunately.